# Do your Pokemon gain experience when you catch Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-fifth-generation

If I am trying to level a Pokemon (Munna, for example), so I wander around and battle lots of wild Pokemon, and then I decide to catch one of these wild Pokemon (because I don't have it yet), will my Munna (or whoever I was using during that battle) still get experience points (EXP) for that battle? Or do you only get EXP if you actually make the Pokemon faint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Pokemon Generations 1-5 you do not gain experience from catching, however in Pokemon Generations 6+ (X and Y, and Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire), You do indeed gain Exp From catching Pokemon

Answer (score 4):

No, you only get experience points for opposing Pokemon that faint in battle.

Answer (score 3):

In the 6th Generation of games (X/Y and ORAS), you **do** gain a (smaller) amount of experience from catching.

> In Generation VI, experience can also be obtained after catching a wild Pokémon.
>
> [- Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Experience_gain_in_battle)

Comment: Any source for the "(smaller)"?

Answer (score 1):

Your Pokemon get experience only if you defeat the wild Pokemon or a trainer's Pokemon.